# ASP.NET Capture user input from textbox that is initially populated from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to capture user input from a text box in a gridview that is initially populated by the database. However my code only captures the initial database value and not what is actually in the text box.

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCartList" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowSelect="gvCartList_Select" OnRowDeleting="gvCartList_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvCartList_Select" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShoppingCartItemID" HeaderText="ShoppingCartItemID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ShoppingCartItemID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShoppingCartID" HeaderText="ShoppingCartID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ShoppingCartID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StockItemID" HeaderText="StockItemID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="StockItemID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Price" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TestQuantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TestQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" DeleteText="Remove" EditText="Update" SelectText="Update" ShowSelectButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowCancelButton="False" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void gvCartList_Select(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //capture the cartitemID, stockitemID, cartID and quantity and then pass it to the BLL
    MessageUserControl.TryRun(() =>
    {

        GridViewRow agvrow = gvCartList.SelectedRow;
        int cartitemid = int.Parse(agvrow.Cells[0].Text);


        //THESE DO NOT CAPTURE THE CORRECT DATA
        int qty = int.Parse((agvrow.FindControl("TestQuantity") as TextBox).Text);



        //connect to BLL
        SalesController sysmgr = new SalesController();
        sysmgr.UpdateCartItem(cartitemid, qty);

    }, "Quantity Updated", "Quantity successfully updated.");
}
```

I've been unable to find any resources on this specific issue, but if I've missed something please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder how this issue can happen if you are trying to get the value from the text box .. I tried the same what u wrote and it gives me correct result !! .. if you need my code I can send it to you as an answer !!

Comment: I'm incredibly baffled as to why my code doesn't work. In theory the quantity captured should be the value input by the user but the value it ends up capturing is the initial one from the database. Please feel free to post your code, I would love to test it!